# How can I read each column separately from a tsv data file?

Tags: python, parsing, dataset, csv

I wrote the following python code to read columns namely ID, Age, Gender, Country, Registered from a tsv text file.

```
import csv
IDs=[]
Genders=[]
Ages=[]
Countrys=[]
Registereds=[]
with open('Sample data.txt','r') as f:
    next(f) # skip headings
    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for ID,Gender,Age,Country,Registered in reader:
        IDs.append(ID)
        Genders.append(Gender)
        Ages.append(Age)
        Countrys.append(Country)
        Registereds.append(Registered)
    pass
```

But it doesn't work and throws following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ext_col.py", line 34, in <module>
    for ID,Gender,Age,Country,Registered in reader:
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Text file has following data with over 100s of line :

```
ID  Gender  Age Country Registered
user_000001 m       Japan   Aug 13, 2006
user_000002 f       Peru    Feb 24, 2006
user_000003 m   22  United States   Oct 30, 2005
user_000004 f           Apr 26, 2006
user_000005 m       Bulgaria    Jun 29, 2006
user_000006     24  Russian Federation  May 18, 2006
user_000007 f       United States   Jan 22, 2006
user_000008 m   23  Slovakia    Sep 28, 2006
user_000009 f   19  United States   Jan 13, 2007
user_000010 m   19  Poland  May 4, 200
```

This is just a small piece of data from that text file.

Further how can I store each column's data in separate text files so I can easily use them in algorithms afterwards simply by opening the required column file wherever necessary? This is actually my ultimate goal here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('test.txt') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
...     for row in reader:
...     # append your lists
...         print(row['ID'], row['Gender'])
```

A Dict Reader uses the header level column names to create a dictionary using the column header as the key, and cell as the value.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. This code works like charm and its worth accepting.

Comment: Furthermore if I were to store the data of a column for e.g Gender in a separate text file without losing the original formatting i.e I wanna preserve any blank line in the column if for e.g. for a given user, his Gender wasn't there in the dataset file then how can I do that efficiently provided the size of whole dataset is 2.5 GB?

Comment: "efficiently" is a hard topic without digging further into a code base.. I would just just check for the empty string. `if row['Gender'] == "" : #write a new line`

Comment: Done adding that last line of code. Extracted column data is now same as in original dataset. Thanks again @Busturdust.

Answer (score 0):

csv.reader() returns a list of strings, your code expects a tuple.

This should work instead:

```
    for row in reader:
        IDs.append(row[0])
        Genders.append(row[1])
        Ages.append(row[2])
        Countrys.append(row[3])
        Registereds.append(row[4])
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed up with the changes you pointed out  but the code again throws an error i.e. IDs.append(row[0]) IndexError: list index out of range. Any further suggestions would be great.

Comment: @VivekP20 please show first 10 lines of you data file, as it really is.

Comment: I just edited the question with correct formatting of dataset I have. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you also print `row` out -- If you arent getting a list properly, your tsv might be malformed